# Vue component table adding row

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating tabe by Vue component. I want to add rows in table by clicking on button "Add". But it works wrong way. When I'm clicking button "Add", I'm seeing that row adding to the table, but it immediatly removing back. I'm suggesting that it happands because of Vue reactivity, but I could not undersand what I'm doing wrong. Please show me where is my mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Titles</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id = "app" >
    <conf-table v-on:add-panel="addPanel" :table = "tabledata" ></conf-table>
</form>

<template id = "table-template">
    <div>
        <table class="lowertable">
            <tr>
                <th width="220"><div id= "ConvHeader">No.</div></th>
                <th width="130" >Panel</th>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(elem, index) in table" :key = "index">
                <td >{{elem.id}}</td>
                <td ><input id = "convConfTable_nr" name="" type="search" :value=elem.name /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input v-on:click="addPanelChild" class="button" name="button" type="submit" value="Add" />        
        </div>
</template>

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script th:inline = "javascript">
    

    var tableData = [];

    Vue.component('conf-table', {
        template: "#table-template",
        props: ['table'],
        methods: {
            addPanelChild: function() {

                this.$emit("add-panel");
            },
        }});

    var vueApp = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            tabledata:  tableData,

        },
        methods: {
            addPanel: function() {

                var panel = {
                    id: 77,
                    name: "Qwerty"
                };

                this.tabledata.push(panel);
            }
        }
    })  

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: at a guess your `form` is being `submit`ted somehow ... perhaps because your `button` is `type="submit"` ... change that to `type="button"` - then re-think why you even need a form if you're never going to submit data to your backend

Answer (score 0):

The problem had been sloved by changing `<form id = "app" >` to `<div id = "app" >`. In some reason Vue application was working wrong then it mounted to `<form>` tag.